# Decompyle .pyc failed

Tags: python, marshalling, decompiling, pyc

From my pyc file I got an error:

```
>>> from decompile import main
>>> main('','.',['D:\\uiexchange.pyc'])
### Can't decompyle  D:\uiexchange.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in ?
    main('','.',['D:\\uiexchange.pyc'])
  File "decompile\__init__.py", line 161, in main
    decompyle_file(infile, outstream, showasm, showast)
  File "decompile\__init__.py", line 101, in decompyle_file
    version, co = _load_module(filename)
  File "decompile\__init__.py", line 49, in _load_module
        co = marshal.load(fp)

ValueError: bad marshal data
```

this is my pyc file
http://www5.zippyshare.com/v/92967047/file.html

maybe do you know why I got this error, and how to fix it ?

Comment: What project is `decompile` from? What version of Python is this?

Comment: it's in python 2.2 
I want to decompile it for learn how it's made. Could you try decompile it ?